# angular workspace with different packages for each app in the workspace

Tags: angular, package.json

i am using anuglar workspace which contains 2 apps

```
"app1" : {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "./src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {....}}

app2 : {
       "root": "./projects/app2/",
      "sourceRoot": "./projects/app2/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {....}}
```

,but i want to specify package.json for each app to install different packages for each so i can make each app build smaller